# How to plot JSON data on mapbox?

Tags: json, mapbox, geojson

I have data in this format:[JSON Data](https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects?format=json&countryshortname_exact=India&source=IBRD&kw=N&rows=10)

but mapbox is not accepting data in this format. I searched a lot to convert this data into geojson but could not find any better way. How do I plot this type of data on the map? Any suggestions?

Edit:
My question is how do I format this type of data so it will be accepted by mapbox.

Answer (score 0):

This kotlin script queries a datasette API and then plots them on a static mapbox image

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/commands/london-hospitals

```
fun staticMap(start: Location, hospitals: List<Location>): String {
  var markers = mutableListOf<String>();
  markers.add("pin-m-marker+CCC(" + start.longitude + "," + start.latitude + ")");

  hospitals.forEach {
    markers.add("pin-s-hospital(" + it.longitude + "," + it.latitude + ")");
  }

  return "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.dark/${markers.joinToString(",")}/auto/800x800.png";
}
```